# Limit enum selection to be unique for several attributes

Tags: xml, enums, xsd, unique

I have following xml output from xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test xmlns="http://www.example.org/test" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/test test.xsd ">
  <Board1>
    <Port1>a</Port1>
    <Port2>b</Port2>
    <Port3>a</Port3>
  </Board1>
  <Board2>
    <Port1>c</Port1>
    <Port2>a</Port2>
    <Port3>d</Port3>
  </Board2>
</Test>
```

The example is that 2 boards shall be connected to 6 ports (a-f) and a port can only be used once. 
I want to use uniqe in xsd so the user only can select a-f once for any of the ports. But I can't get it working.

```
<element name="Test" type="tns:Test_Type">
        <unique name="unique_PortId">
                <selector xpath="Test/*" /> 
                <field xpath="[starts-with(name()'Port')]"/> 
        </unique>
 </element>
```

Does anyone know how to have this check in the xsd file?

16/4 I have solved it, here is the xsd code I'm using:

```
<xsd:element name="Test" type="Test_Type">
    <xsd:unique name="unique_PortId">
    <xsd:selector xpath="*" /> 
    <xsd:field xpath="*/."/> 
    </xsd:unique>
</xsd:element>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, your example above should raise an error, because 'a' is found 3 times?

Comment: Exactly the letter a shall only be able to be selected once.